# How to capture SQL management studio traffic with Fiddler?

Tags: sql-server, fiddler

By default Fiddler will not capture queries sent from my local Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

How do I configure Fiddler to capture the traffic?

I cannot modify the server, so it must be local changes.

Comment: why don't you use SQL Profiler or trace ?

Comment: Yes, profiler is the way to go. But I think you should be looking for "TDS" packets.

Comment: @squirrel because I want to see the network traffic.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can't. Fiddler monitors http traffic - the database engine does not use http for communication.

Comment: No, you're not. Looks like WireShark is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[smor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441700/how-to-capture-sql-management-studio-traffic-with-fiddler?noredirect=1#comment93767135_53441700) commented with the right answer: "Unless I'm missing something, you can't. Fiddler monitors http traffic - the database engine does not use http for communication."